# Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type. [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, tflite

I am using flutter_tflite for prediction on image.
please help if someone have solution.
the model successfully loaded but when i apply on image it giving this error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32).

here is some code samples

i applied Prediction on image using runModelOnImage function:

```
void applyPredictions() async {
    print(pickedImage!.path);
    try {
      var prediction = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
          path: pickedImage!.path,
          imageMean: 224,
          imageStd: 224,
          numResults: 2,
          threshold: 0.05,
          asynch: true
          );
      print("prediction----> $prediction");
      setState(() {
        // _output = prediction;
        _loading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("error--->$e");
    }
  }
```

I am also tried to convert image in binary :
here the binary functions that i used,

```
 void applyPredictions() async {

    Uint8List inputImageData = await loadImage(pickedImage!.path);

    print(pickedImage!.path);
    try {
      var prediction = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
        binary: inputImageData
          // path: pickedImage!.path,
          // imageMean: 224,
          // imageStd: 224,
          // numResults: 2,
          // threshold: 0.05,
          // asynch: true
          );
      print("prediction----> $prediction");
      setState(() {
        // _output = prediction;
        _loading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("error--->$e");
    }
  }



void applyPredictions() async {

    Uint8List inputImageData = await loadImage(pickedImage!.path);

    print(pickedImage!.path);
    try {
      var prediction = await Tflite.runModelOnBinary(
        binary: inputImageData
       
          );
      print("prediction----> $prediction");
      setState(() {
        // _output = prediction;
        _loading = false;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print("error--->$e");
    }
  }
```

here loadImage function :

```
Future<Uint8List> loadImage(String imagePath) async {
    // Load the image using the 'image' package
    final image = img.decodeImage(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync());

    // Resize the image to the required dimensions (224x224)
    final resizedImage = img.copyResize(image!, width: 224, height: 224);

    // Initialize a Uint8List to hold the converted image data
    final imageBytes = Uint8List(1 * 224 * 224 * 3);

    // Apply quantization and populate the imageBytes array
    int pixelIdx = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < 224; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 224; x++) {
        final pixel = resizedImage.getPixel(x, y);

        // Quantization formula
        imageBytes[pixelIdx++] = ((pixel & 0xFF - 127) * 0.007843137718737125).toInt() & 0xFF; // Blue channel
        imageBytes[pixelIdx++] = (((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF - 127) * 0.007843137718737125).toInt() & 0xFF; // Green channel
        imageBytes[pixelIdx++] = (((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF - 127) * 0.007843137718737125).toInt() & 0xFF; // Red channel
      }
    }

    return imageBytes;
  }
```

I also tried this function for conversion to binary

```
 Uint8List convertImageToTensorFormat(String imagePath) {
    // Load the image
    final image = img.decodeImage(File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync());

    // Resize the image to the desired dimensions (224x224)
    final resizedImage = img.copyResize(image!, width: 224, height: 224);

    // Create a Uint8List to hold the converted data
    final tensorData = Uint8List(1 * 224 * 224 * 3);

    // Apply quantization and copy pixel values into the tensorData
    for (var y = 0; y < 224; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 224; x++) {
        final pixel = resizedImage.getPixel(x, y);

        // Apply quantization formula
        final quantizedRed = (0.007843137718737125 * (pixel & 0xFF - 127)).toInt();
        final quantizedGreen = (0.007843137718737125 * ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF - 127)).toInt();
        final quantizedBlue = (0.007843137718737125 * ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF - 127)).toInt();

        // Write the quantized values to the tensorData as UINT8
        final offset = 3 * (y * 224 + x);
        tensorData[offset] = quantizedBlue & 0xFF;
        tensorData[offset + 1] = quantizedGreen & 0xFF;
        tensorData[offset + 2] = quantizedRed & 0xFF;
      }
    }

    // Return the tensor data
    return tensorData;
  }
```

on this function i am getting this issue :  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_sequential_1_input:0) with 150528 bytes from a Java Buffer with 602112 bytes.

[image: these are the model properties]